# Solving Equation $\lfloor|x|\rfloor+\lfloor |y|\rfloor=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I solve this equation for $(x,y)$?

> $$\lfloor|x|\rfloor+\lfloor |y|\rfloor=3$$

Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: What does $[a]$ mean?

Comment: $[a]$ is greatest integer function.

Comment: Do you mean the [floor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Definition_and_properties)?

Comment: Oh, yes floor function.

Comment: I edited the question to include a more common notation.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is symmetrical in all Quadrant because $f(x,y) = f(-x,y) = f(x,-y) = f(x,y)$

where $f(x,y) = \lfloor |x|\rfloor +\lfloor |y|\rfloor - 3 = 0$

So I have calculate here for only $\bf{(I^{st})}$ Quadrant.

Given :: $\lfloor |x|\rfloor +\lfloor |y|\rfloor  = 3$

$\bullet $ If $\lfloor |x|\rfloor =0$ and $\lfloor |y|\rfloor = 3$

Then $0<|x|<1$ and $3 \leq |y|<4$

$\bullet $ If $\lfloor |x|\rfloor =1$ and $\lfloor |y|\rfloor = 2$

Then $1\leq |x|<2$ and $2 \leq |y|<3$

$\bullet $ If $\lfloor |x|\rfloor =2$ and $\lfloor |y|\rfloor = 1$

Then $2\leq |x|<3$ and $1 \leq |y|<2$

$\bullet $ If $\lfloor |x|\rfloor =3$ and $\lfloor |y|\rfloor = 0$

Then $3\leq |x|<4$ and $0< |y|<1$

Now you will find Corrosponding Intervals for $x$ and $y$

Similarly for other $3$ Quadrants.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Both terms are non-negative integers